# Why am I able to switch user only using hyphen?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, sudoers

If I try to switch the user using `sudo su - kshitiz` it works, and doesn't ask me for any password.

But if I do `sudo su kshitiz` it asks me for that user's password.

Why is this? I understand that hyphen loads that user's environment variables where's no hyphen keeps my own.

So then why does it ask me for target user's password when I want to switch while keeping my own variables, but not when I switch and load target's profile?

Answer (score 1):

In recent util-linux releases, `su` and `su -l` use different PAM configurations – `/etc/pam.d/su` and `/etc/pam.d/su-l` respectively. It's possible that the latter configuration is either missing on your system, or doesn't have the usual `pam_wheel` module (which normally allows root to switch to any other user).

Just use `sudo -s -u kshitiz` or `sudo -i -u kshitiz` directly; the `su` is redundant.

Comment: @Gravity `sudo -s -u` or `sudo -i -u` doesn't work it asks for password. The only thing working is `sudo su -`